# Running JS after popup dialog shows up

Tags: javascript, liferay-aui, liferay-7

I would like to run javascript code after the frontend image editor dialog shows up. How can I do that? That's what I have so far:

```
function ${namespace}editWithImageEditor(
    editItemURL, uploadItemURL, fileEntryFilename, fileEntrySrc) {

    Liferay.Util.editEntity(
        {
            dialog: {
                destroyOnHide: true,
                zIndex: 100000
            },
            id: 'dlImageEditor',
            stack: false,
            title: '${editLanguageKey} ' + fileEntryFilename,
            uri: editItemURL,
            urlParams: {
                entityURL: fileEntrySrc,
                saveParamName: 'imageEditorFileName',
                saveURL: uploadItemURL
            },
            dialogIframe: {
                after: {
                    load: function(event) {}
                }
            }
        },
        AUI().bind('${namespace}_onSaveEditSuccess', this)
    );
}
```

It works, but it's executing before all dialog content is loaded. How to run script after the dialog is fully loaded? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using the events here https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/domready.html

Answer (score -1):

just add a delay/timeout to delay the javascript you want to run, I've made the delay here 1 second, but you could make it as short or as long as you'd want

```
function ${namespace}editWithImageEditor(
editItemURL, uploadItemURL, fileEntryFilename, fileEntrySrc) {

Liferay.Util.editEntity(
    {
        dialog: {
            destroyOnHide: true,
            zIndex: 100000
        },
        id: 'dlImageEditor',
        stack: false,
        title: '${editLanguageKey} ' + fileEntryFilename,
        uri: editItemURL,
        urlParams: {
            entityURL: fileEntrySrc,
            saveParamName: 'imageEditorFileName',
            saveURL: uploadItemURL
        },
        dialogIframe: {
            after: {
                load: window.setTimeout(function(event) {
                          //code here
                      }, 1000)
                }
            }
        }
    },
    AUI().bind('${namespace}_onSaveEditSuccess', this)
);
```

}

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's not an ideal answer but it's helpful!

Comment: yea, I admit it's not really the best thing to do, but it's the easiest. (also if the person who downvoted ever sees this answer again, could he please provide some constructive critisism? :3)

Comment: There's no guarantee this will work. The time you set is arbitrary, and the code may execute before or after the dialog content is loaded. Both you and the OP have admitted that it's not a good solution so -1.